# Quais recursos utilizar na criação de uma extensão Chrome para notificações

Tags: google-chrome-extensão

Quero criar uma extensão Chrome que verifique periódicamente uma URI contendo resposta `JSON` e que exiba uma notificação para o usuário (em alguns casos).
Isto deve acontecer, independente do website onde o usuário está navegando.

Vou criar um exemplo de uso:

- Extensão Sorteio Exemplo;
- A cada 2h recolhe o `JSON`, e se nele existir a chave `cupom`, exibe o alerta;
- O alerta diz ao usuário: "Você ganhou! Informe o cupom valor da chave `cupom` recebido no `json`.

**Que recursos e permissões Chrome devo utilizar?**

Extra: Alguém conhece algum exemplo ou open source que trabalhe semelhante ao exemplo que criei?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na documentação do Google Chrome extensions existe bastante exemplos, você pode estar dando uma olhada para adaptar ao seu projeto.

[Exemplos Google Chrome Extensions (Inglês)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#idle---simple-example)

Você pode usar JQuery para fazer essa aplicação, aqui também há um [exemplo](http://carl-topham.com/theblog/post/creating-chrome-extension-uses-jquery-manipulate-dom-page/) de como iniciar com Jquery.